# How can I speed up my rate of sending event to AzureEventHub?

Tags: c#, azure, foreach, azure-eventhub

I am using this simple foreach loop to send events to an Azure EventHub, problem is it seems failry slow and only sends 1-2 events / second, so I feel I must be missing something, how can I speed this up? am I sending them async or what am I doing wrong?

```
 if (!apiInputPutCalendarService.TimeSlotIdsToClose.Any())
                {
                    return new BadRequestObjectResult(new
                    {
                        Status = "NOK",
                        Error = "There are no timeslots to close",
                        Result = ""
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (String calendarTimeSlotId in apiInputPutCalendarService.TimeSlotIdsToClose)
                    {
                        EventHubCDSSoftDeleteTriggerModel scanMsg = new EventHubCDSSoftDeleteTriggerModel
                        {
                            TimeSlotId = calendarTimeSlotId
                        };

                        var scanMessageJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(scanMsg);

                        await EventHubHelper.SendEventToEventHubAsync(_eventHubClient, scanMessageJsonString);

                        log.LogInformation($"Message: {scanMessageJsonString} sent!");
                    }
                }
```

its such a small simple message I expected at least 100s of messages to be sent / second

What am I missing here?

Comment: From the variable naming, it looks like you're using the legacy Event Hubs SDK.   I'd recommend upgrading to the current generation package, `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs`, which is what Peter is demonstrating in the answer below.

Comment: In addition to Peter's advice about publishing in batches, you may also want to consider the number of [throughput units](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-scalability#throughput-units) that you're using and the [quotas](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas) that are applied to each Event Hubs tier.  Together, those cap ingress and egress traffic and may cause throttling for large payloads or very frequent publishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, have you measured the impact of the logging and the serialization and the call to `TimeSlotIdsToClose`? Also, I would start  by not sending the messages one by one but by sending messages in batches:

```cs
await using (var producerClient = new EventHubProducerClient(connectionString, eventHubName))
        {
            // Create a batch of events 
            using EventDataBatch eventBatch = await producerClient.CreateBatchAsync();

            // Add events to the batch. An event is a represented by a collection of bytes and metadata. 
            eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("First event")));
            eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Second event")));
            eventBatch.TryAdd(new EventData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Third event")));

            // Use the producer client to send the batch of events to the event hub
            await producerClient.SendAsync(eventBatch);
            Console.WriteLine("A batch of 3 events has been published.");
        }
```

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-dotnet-standard-getstarted-send#send-events))

Do mind that the code above does not reuse the `EventHubProducerClient`, which is recommended and that you shouldn't ignore te result of `TryAdd` as that will tell you whether the message can be added to the batch (there is a size based limit per batch).

Also, since I don't know your code:

> Each of the Event Hubs client types is safe to cache and use as a singleton for the lifetime of the application, which is best practice when events are being published or read regularly.

([Source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/README.md#client-lifetime))

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding the sample shown, as it is demonstrating an anti-pattern for client lifetime and ignoring the results of `TryAdd`, which can lead to data loss.   I'd recommend using the [publishing samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample04_PublishingEvents.md) as a model until we're able to get the quick-start fixed.

Comment: I know, but I got it straight from the docs ;-) Main takeaway is to use batching and reuse the client .

Comment: Yeah, it's a very fair point.  The quick-start guides are flat out wrong and we're still working with the folks that own them to get things corrected.

Comment: Sending in batches made a massive difference I also added multiple senders now things a really flying